# Login form with Catel

Tags: c#, xaml, catel

I'm continuing my experiments with Catel and was wondering a couple of things :

- Can I invert the Ok/Cancel button?
- How can I show the login as a splash screen? I've searched and I've found an example with Prism but here I don't have the Bootstrapper

Here's my code

```
 private   void OnMenuClickExecute(Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var typeFactory = this.GetServiceLocator();
        var dependencyResolver = this.GetDependencyResolver();
        var uiVisualizerService = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IUIVisualizerService>();

        var login = typeFactory.ResolveType<LoginViewModel>();


        IViewLocator locator = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IViewLocator>();

        uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog(login);
```

The View

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="CatelDocking.Login.Views.LoginView"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
               xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

<catel:StackGrid>
    <catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
    </catel:StackGrid.RowDefinitions>
    <catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="120"  />
    </catel:StackGrid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Content="Username"></Label>
    <Label Content="Password" Grid.Row="1"></Label>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Username,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Password,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
    <telerik:RadButton Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Ok"></telerik:RadButton>
</catel:StackGrid>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, use Custom mode and add the buttons using the AddCustomButton in the code-behind of the window
2. That's something that you can find out yourself as a developer, works the same for all fx / wpf, but something like this should be sufficient:

`uiVisualizerService.ShowDialog<LoginViewModel>();`

Comment: Geert that's the solution I adopted till now (but for now I click on button to show login form...) which is the most correct point to load this form at?

Comment: and also...is there a way I can put the inverted button in a single place for all of my window?

Comment: Just derive from data window and implement your own version. Then you can change it for all your windows.

Comment: The right moment of loading something completely depends on the app. For example, we created a shell with splash screen in Orchestra. We show licensing during the splash screen, but others prefer to fully load the shell and show the login screen. It's up to you

Comment: Geert, what I was meaning is suppose I've to load a viewmodel and load some data to fill a dropdown, where should I load those data in the viewmodel at which event? Initialize?

Comment: Yes, Initialize is the method to use.

Comment: Excuse me Geert is there a way I can apply the inverted buttons position in the whole application? as I've seen it's the WrapControlHelper that does the trick https://github.com/Catel/Catel/blob/5eebb822721ecfae4b815a4ff4fcea1b2ee071ed/src/Catel.MVVM/Catel.MVVM.Shared/Windows/Helpers/WrapControlHelper.cs but I think I can't override it easily

Comment: Just a question Geert, when I'm in the login form and  I click ok, an OkCommand is sent at buttonclick how can I call a service, validate credentials and if there's an error don't close the dialog?

Comment: You can either implement it in the Save method on the VM or implement a custom command for this.